# Selenium test (python) on slider with angular js based UI

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, selenium, testing

I am trying to set a UI slider (Label=ON/OFF, Slider, Apply button) based on Angular JS with selenium.

example code:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/2pk3m/2)

Tried next python code:
(instead of send_keys I used java-script; since send_keys is not working visualy)

```
slider = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='range']") 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '1';", slider) 
time.sleep(5) # or ... 
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)      
action.move_to_element_with_offset(slider, 90, 2).click() 
action.perform()
```

Visually the python code perform well the job: moving my slider from left to right and the click on the element (with offset on the right side). But the label 'strong' does not change to ON and also (verified with Firebug->Net) after I press Apply the value sent to back-end is OFF (and not ON as expected).

Please let me know about any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: What am I missing that made you put your code in comments? :-S

Comment: Initially added in comments because of some  stackoverflow editor issues !?! ...

Comment: here is a similar example: http://jsfiddle.net/bmleite/2pk3m/2/

Comment: possible it is about synthetic vs native events (Firefox, XUbuntu)

Comment: used Selenium RC and it is working OK (server and client on the same Linux PC). 'action' does not exists in Selenium RC, so I have used regular click (without offset).

Answer (score 0):

Fix with RemoteWebDriver (webdriver + server localhost)

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp